# Generate and run SAS-code based on data in file

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have written several SAS macro functions, each of them has some input parameters. Let's say for this example that this functions are:

```
%macro add(dataset,column,number);
data &dataset;
    set &dataset;
    &column = &column + &number;
run;
%mend;
```

and

```
%macro multiply(dataset,column,number);
data &dataset;
    set &dataset;
    &column = &column * &number;
run;
%mend;
```

What i want to do is to create separate file which will contain sequence of calls if this functions. Example of content could be:

- add, work.tmp, value, 3;
- add, work.tmp, value2, 5;
- multiply, work.tmp, value, 2;
- ...

Can you please advice me the best way to run all this sequence of calls? Do i have to right a macro which will produce SAS code based on this file and than run it? Or there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: Try googling for `sas data-driven programming` - this will tell you a great deal more about this sort of thing in general.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just write another SAS program that calls the macros. Your example file is so very close to this. Just surround each line of parameters with %add() or %multiply()

Another technique (though more complex) is to write a data step that reads your instruction file, parses it, and makes repeated call execute statements to invoke your macros.